# How to properly use the try() function

Tags: r, try-catch

I run a code that use xtabs in order to present binary classification preformances.I use this line of code ( inside a loop ):

```
g<-xtabs(~BAIsuP+glm_predict_response,data=test)
g11<-((g[1,1]+g[2,2])/(g[1,1]+g[2,2]+g[1,2]+g[2,1]))
print(g11)
```

However from time to time there is not enough observations and I get an `error:Error in g[2, 2] : subscript out of bounds`
So I tried this line of code but I didn't see any change,What have I missed?

```
g<-try(xtabs(~BAIsuP+glm_predict_response,data=test),silent = TRUE)
print(g)
```

Comment: What would you like it to output? Whenever `try` (with `silent=TRUE`) finds an error it just continues silently.

Comment: The issue is that I get the same error. I thought It will continue to the next line of the script.I know the problem hance the silent=TRUE

Comment: Then your error probably doesn't occur in `xtabs` but somewhere else in the loop. That's why reproducible examples are always required :)

Comment: The error indicates that the error is from the xtabs : Error in g[2, 2] .That means that it cant compute the second row and column of the xtabs.As far as I know.

Comment: Would be good to have a reproducible example then to check. Your error shows to me that the problem comes after the creation of `g` and `g` does not exist until `xtabs` has finished. Which tells me that `xtabs` is working fine.

Comment: You are right  @LyzandeR, The problem was on the next line that uses the out come from the xtabs,I edited my Q.It is strange that the error desciption indicates a problem in 'g'

Comment: Glad that you found the error :) . Using `try((g[1,1]+g[2,2])/(g[1,1]+g[2,2]+g[1,2]+g[2,1])), silent=TRUE)` will solve your problem now.

Comment: You are very welcome :)